# setTimeout scope issue

Tags: javascript

I have a setTimeout defined inside of a function that controls the player's respawn (i am creating a game):

```
var player = {
    ...
    death:(function() {
        this.alive = false;
        Console.log("death!");
        var timer3 = setTimeout((function() {
            this.alive = true;
            Console.log("alive!");
        }),3000);
    }),
    ...
}
```

When it executes, I read in the console, "death!" and 3 seconds later "alive!". However, `alive` is never really set back to true, because if i write `player.alive` in the console, it returns `false`. How come i can see "alive!" but the variable is never set back to true?

Comment: in this scope `this` is the anonymous function passed to the setTimeout, you need to assign `this` to some other variable and check it later

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to be careful with `this`. You need to assign your `this` in the outer scope to a variable. The `this` keyword *always* refers to the `this` of the current scope, which changes any time you wrap something in `function() { ... }`.

```
var thing = this;
thing.alive = false;
Console.log("death!");
var timer3 = setTimeout((function() {
    thing.alive = true;
    Console.log("alive!");
}),3000);
```

This should give you better success.

**Update 2019-10-09:** The original answer is true, but another option is now available for recent versions of JavaScript. Instead of using `function`, you can use an arrow function instead, which does not modify `this`:

```
this.alive = false;
Console.log("death!");
var timer3 = setTimeout(() => {
    this.alive = true;
    Console.log("alive!");
}), 3000);
```

This is supported from ES6 forward, which is part of all current browsers but IE (of course), I think. If you are using a modern framework to build your project via Babel or whatever, the framework should make sure this works as expected everywhere.

Comment: For extra credit, read up on javascript's function `.call()` and `.apply()` methods, which help to understand how `this` works in javascript, and can come in handy when you need to define the function somewhere other than where you're passing it.  jQuery's `.proxy()` and Prototype's `.bind()` provide neat wrappers to this functionality.

Comment: Further to what @BrianMortenson said, JS has its own [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (introduced in version 1.8.5, so not supported in older IE). Actually one of the examples on that MDN page is for use with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Further to what @nnnnnn said, if you are using ES6 you can use arrowed functions. 

() => setTimeout( ()=> this.alive = true, 3000)

Answer (score 25):

It's because `this` in the `setTimeout` handler is referring to `window`, which is presumably not the same value as referenced by `this` outside the handler.

You can cache the outer value, and use it inside...

```
var self = this;

var timer3 = setTimeout((function() {
    self.alive = true;
    Console.log("alive!");
}),3000);
```

---

...or you can use ES5 `Function.prototype.bind`...

```
var timer3 = setTimeout((function() {
    this.alive = true;
    Console.log("alive!");
}.bind(this)),3000);
```

...though if you're supporting legacy implementations, you'll need to add a shim to `Function.prototype`.

- [MDN `Function.prototype.bind` patch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)

---

...or if you're working in an ES6 environment...

```
var timer3 = setTimeout(()=>{
    this.alive = true;
    Console.log("alive!");
},3000);
```

Because there's [no binding of `this` in `Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone reads this, the new javascript syntax allows you to bind a scope to a function with "bind":

```
window.setTimeout(this.doSomething.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately binding directly to the function like this doesn't appear to work (at least, not in Chrome 60). It seems that you have to run it through an anonymous function first, as in the "community wiki" ES5 example above.

Answer (score 5):

Probably because `this` isn't preserved in the timeout callback. Try:

```
var that = this;
...
var timer3 = setTimeout(function() {
    that.alive = true;
    ...
```

**Update (2017)** - or use a lambda function, which will implicitly capture `this`:

```
var timer3 = setTimeout(() => {
    this.alive = true;
    ...
```

Comment: In my humble opinion the `that = this` solution should not be used anymore because it only adds to the confusion caused by the `this` keyword. Preferably you should use arrow notation `setInterval( () => {})` or else use `bind()` to fix javascript's scoping issues.

Comment: @Kokodoko I agree!  This was answered in 2012.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

With ES6 function syntax, the scope for 'this' doesn't change inside setTimeout:

```
var timer3 = setTimeout((() => {
    this.alive = true;
    console.log("alive!");
}), 3000);
```