# setTimeout function not working with value change

Tags: javascript, jquery

setTimeout function is not working as per the expectations.
Here's my code:

```
$(document).delegate('.pur','click', function(e){
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#qua').val();
    if(quantity>0){
        this.value='Adding';
    }
    else{
        this.value='Min 100';
        setTimeout(function(){this.value='Buy now'}, 3000);
    }
});
```

Above code doesn't work at all, it doesn't change the value after 3 seconds as it's expected to do. Any flaw or something in it? Can anyone help finding what's wrong with it?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11714397/1633510), same issue. The problem is the scope of `this`, you should create a reference to it outside of the `setTimeout`

Comment: The problem is that the value of `this` in the function you pass to `setTimeout()` won't be what you want it to be.

Comment: Yes, got it, problem solved, please make it your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to "this" in the anonymous function does not point to anything. You could change it like this (i.e., `self` being a variable in the visibility scope of your anonymous function):

```
     this.value='Min 100'; 
     var self = this;
     setTimeout(function(){self.value='Buy now'}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Scoping issue

inside your setTimeout, "this" doesn't refer to the same object as outside setTimeout.

Fix it like this

```
$(document).delegate('.pur','click', function(e){
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('#qua').val();
    if(quantity>0){
        this.value='Adding';
    }
   else{
       this.value='Min 100';
       var that = this; // hold a reference to "this" as "that" 
       setTimeout(function(){that.value='Buy now'}, 3000); // use "that" instead of   "this"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also do the trick

```
setTimeout(function() { this.value = 'Buy now'; }.bind(this), 3000)
```