# How to properly scope function to run on delay in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, delay

I am trying to add the input data into an array delayed for 2 seconds after the last keystroke.  However, when I run this I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this._validateInput is not a function`

How can I properly scope `this._validateInput()` to run on delay?

I tried `let func = this._validateInput();`, but that seems to run the function every time that func is set.

Also, the on-change input handler only fires when the input loses focus.

Looking for away to solve this...

```
<paper-input id="itemId" on-input="_autoAddToArray"></paper-input>
```

...

```
_validateInput () {
    console.log('validate input');
}

_autoAddToArray () {
  let timeout = null;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    this._validateInput();
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: where is `_validateInput()` defined?

Comment: Same level as ```_autoAddToArray```.  Updated the question to match...

Comment: then why are you using `this._validateInput()`. Just use `_validateInput()`

Comment: I get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: _validateInput is not defined``` when I try that...

Comment: can u share fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hmh03vzc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a lambda:

```
setTimeout(
    () => this._validateInput(),
    2000
);
```

or bind the function

```
setTimeout(this._validateInput.bind(this), 2000);
```

Either solution should work

---

The lambda works because it doesn't have its own scope.
The binding works because it applies the scope "before" running it so to speak

Comment: Do you know which method has the best performance?  Setting ```this``` to ```self``` seems really inefficient.

Comment: well, I know this is native. There is no overhead. So I don't know what could be MORE performant than this

Comment: AFAIK this returns the entire Polymer element, which is much larger than a single function.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword always refers to the `this` of the current scope, which changes any time you wrap something in function() { ... }

You need to assign your `this` in the outer scope to a variable.

```
var self = this;
timeout = setTimeout(function () {
  self._validateInput();
}, 2000);
```

Reference: [setTimeout scope issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714397/settimeout-scope-issue)

Comment: You might have a typo there, the dot at the end of the first line. Also please note that you can also pass `this` as the 3rd argument and you will get it as a parameter in your callback, and use it under some other name, like `context`, for example. Also, if you're ok with using ES6 you can use the arrow function syntax for your callback and since there's no binding on `this` you won't have this problem.

Comment: thanks @mishu. I corrected typo. passing this as 3rd parameter seems to be working in modern browsers. but this functionality is not available in the old browsers.

Comment: if you want to support Internet Explorer 9 and below in a polymer based application I'm guessing that the setTimeout support (that can be patched with a polyfill) is the least of your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<paper-input id="itemId" on-input="_autoAddToArray"></paper-input>
```

...

```
_autoAddToArray () {
  let timeout = null;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
    let that = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      that._validateInput();
    }, 2000);
}

_validateInput () {
  if(this.$.itemId.value) {
    // do something
  }
}
```