# Infinite scroll not working in Listview React Native

Tags: android, listview, react-native, pagination

i want pagination in my react native application so below is my code

```
 <ListView bounces={false}
          enableEmptySections={ true }
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={ false }
          dataSource={this.state.dataSourceRadio}
          renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderSiteView(rowData, rowID)}
          onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
        />

onEndReached() {
if (!this.state.waiting) {

    this.state.offset=10,
    this.APIGetSiteGPS(this.state.token); 
}
```

}

When i run above code next page data not come so any idea how can i solve this? your all suggestion are appreciable

I update my view in this method

```
 _bindingRadioButtonData(data) {


this.setState({

  dataSourceRadio:  this.state.dataSourceRadio.cloneWithRows(data),
})
```

}

API call methods

```
APIGetSiteGPS(token) {
console.log(TAG + "customer Api: " + APPCONSTANTS.BASE_URL + "site" + " " + token)
fetch(APPCONSTANTS.BASE_URL + "site?&offset=" + this.state.offset, {
  method: APPCONSTANTS.API_METHOD.GET,
  headers: {
    'Accept': APPCONSTANTS.HEADERS.VALUE.ACCEPT,
    'Content-Type': APPCONSTANTS.HEADERS.VALUE.CONTENT_TYPE,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
})
  .then(response => {
    const statusCode = response.status;
    const data = response.json();
   // data: offset === 0 ? res.results : [...this.state.siteList, ...res.results];
    return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
  })
  .then((res, data) => {
    this.responseReceive(res)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.stopLoadingIndicator()
    console.log('error..', error);
  })
```

}

```
 responseReceive(response) {

this.stopLoadingIndicator()
console.log(TAG + 'Response-->' + JSON.stringify(response));

var temp = this.state.siteList;

if (response[0] == APPCONSTANTS.API_RESPONSE_STATUS.SUCCESS) {
  for (let i = 0; i < response[1].data.sites.length; i++) {
    temp.push(response[1].data.sites[i]);
  }  

  this.setState({ siteList: temp})

  setTimeout(() => {this._bindingRadioButtonData(this.state.siteList)}, 1000)

  this.setState({isFirstDataLoad:true});

  //this.onEndReached();

} else {
  Alert.alert(APPCONSTANTS.APP_NAME, response[1].message)
}
```

}

Comment: You should provide more info.
When you said `When i run above code next page data not come`, where is your update code for `this.state.dataSourceRadio`?

Comment: @Khoa: see my update question

Comment: I think the use of `this` within your `setTimeout()` is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714413/1346610

Comment: try to remove `setTimeout` and bring the callback of it to `setState` like this: `this.setState({ siteList: temp }, () => this._bindingRadioButtonData(this.state.siteList))`

Comment: 1 more suggestion that: don't use `ListView` (it's deprecated as doc). Try `FlatList` (another official one) for better usage interface and performance (according to docs)