# Why does setTimeout return a number instead of text? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I'm working with Reactjs and I need to show a message using a setTimeout but it always returns a number to me. Does anyone know the reason?

This is my code:

```
  messageError = () => {
       return <h1>Error!</h1>
  }

render() {
  return (
   ...
     { this.props.error.code != undefined ?
                            setTimeout(() => { this.messageError() }, 3000) : null }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `setTimeout` does not return anything like you think here. It returns a positive integer and executes something. Here you are invoking your function but its return value can't be rendered like that. What is your intention here? Why do you want a delay?

Comment: @devserkan thanks. I just want show the error message.

Comment: You are welcome. Ok, but why the delay?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @devserkan I use this in a login form, then I want to show error messages when the user has some erroneous data.

Comment: Then render your component according to this error condition. You don't need any delay here. Even if you need you can't use `setTimeout` like that.

Comment: Just look @Kishan Munda's answer. He is mimicking the error change, so don't get confused about the `setTimeout` there. Your `error` will change in your app depending on some other conditions. Use those conditions and render the message. You don't need `setTimeout` at all. If there is error render the message, if there isn't any error do not render the message.

Comment: Completely agree with @devserkan . setTimeOut should be used wisely. But the reason why you are not getting the message printed is because of the scope issue, I guess. Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714397/settimeout-scope-issue

Comment: I think the scope is not the problem here. Problem is `setTimeout` just returns an integer, nothing more. It can do things but can't return anything beside that integer. So invoking a function does not work like that. Also, the callback is an arrow function here, the scope wouldn't be the problem if it was the real problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are doing wrong way. As my understanding you want something else. I'm giving yu one example, it might help.

```
class MyComponent {
  state = {
    error: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        error: true,
      })
    }, 3000);
  }

  renderMessageError() {
    return <h1>Error</h1>
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return this.renderMessageError();
    }

    return null; //
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn, I was going to give nearly the exact same code :) With a 2 seconds delay and some ternary operator :)

Comment: Your code helped me, I solved it using componentWillReceiveProps. Thanks.

Comment: I would not suggest to use componentWillReceiveProps, this is going to deprecated in newer version of react. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 2):

This is an asynchronous and you can't expect its return value. The number is the ID of setTimeout, used to clear setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what is supposed to do.

setTimeout doesn't pause execution for the indicated time.  It schedules your function to occur later and then returns a value (which is typically a number) that can be used to call that schedule.

The function obviously cannot return a value *from the future*.